# Get Access token from Spotify api

Tags: spotify

I'm trying to get a access token from this endpoint using asp.net: https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token

The token i get back has Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}".

When creating my app over att Spotify Developer i stated my Redirect Uri as http://localhost:59486/ which is my Project Url.

What am i doing wrong?

I have borrowed this method from https://hendrikbulens.wordpress.com/2015/01/07/c-and-the-spotify-web-api-part-i/

```
private async Task<string> GetAccessToken()
        {
            SpotifyToken token = new SpotifyToken();

            string postString = string.Format("grant_type=client_credentials");
            byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postString);

            string url = "https://accounts.spotify.com/api/token";

            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Method = "POST";
            request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic YjlkZj****************************************jQ2YjM3MjE5MDE=");
            request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
            using (Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
                using (WebResponse response = await request.GetResponseAsync())
                {
                    using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                        {
                            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
                            token = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SpotifyToken>(responseFromServer);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            return token.access_token;
        }
```

EDIT:
This is my Http request:

```
spotify.com/api/token HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Yjlk....................5MDE=
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Host: accounts.spotify.com
Content-Length: 29
Expect: 100-continue
Connection: Keep-Alive

grant_type=client_credentials
```

Comment: Could you please debug so that you can see the exact HTTP request made from your service? That'd be a lot more helpful. Obviously hide the `clientId` and `clientSecret`.

Comment: I have now edited my question with the request.

Comment: Is the request actually sent? If so, do you retrieve a response? From your question, it looks like you're not getting a response.

Comment: There was a problem with not sending the request. Not sure why but now it works and i recieve a access token. Thanx!

Comment: One more question though concerning getting new releases. Isn't Country optional? Leaving out country results in no items back. Adding country=se retuns items?